# Select multiple columns and filter on specific and/or conditions then form new Column

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I am using a very large database of patient records.
Basically I am trying to categorize patient based on certain diagnosis codes.
Each patient may have btw 1-10 diagnosis codes in any arrangement (DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5, DX6, DX7,
DX8, DX9,DX10).
I am having difficulty coding with multiple conditions to filter through each DX column as they can
be in different arrangements.

```
Example Dataset: 
DX1<-c("05", "89", "99", "87", "05", "67")
DX2<-c("87", "05", "21", "26", "23", "44","89", "13", "2" )
DX3<-c("04", "99","23", "05", "57", "16", "90", "89", "87")
DX4<-c("05", "26","21")
DX5<-c("67", "86","44", "63", "18", "87", "87", "05")
DX6<-c("75", "06","24", "02", "86", "15", "01", "87")
DX7<-c("86", "87","66", "56", "65", "05", "72")
install.packages("qpcR")                           
library("qpcR")
Patientdata <- qpcR:::cbind.na(DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5, DX6, DX7) 
data.frame(Patientdata)


   DX1 DX2 DX3  DX4  DX5  DX6  DX7
1   05  87  04   05   67   75   86
2   89  05  99   26   86   06   87
3   99  21  23   21   44   24   66
4   87  26  05 NA   63   02   56
5   05  23  57 NA   18   86   65
6   67  44  44 NA   87   15   05
7 NA  89  90 NA   87   01   72
8 NA  13  89 NA   05   87 NA
9 NA   2  87 NA NA NA NA
```

I would like to filter all patients who have a DX with (05, or 5 or 02 or 2 or 62) AND (87 or 087 or
0086 or 089 or 89)

```
Patientdata<- Patientdata%>% mutate_at(vars(DX1, DX2, DX3, DX4, DX5, DX6, DX7),
Diagnosis= ifelse(. %in% c("05"| "5"| "02"| "2"| "36"| "62"|"0062") &
c("87"| "087"| "86"| "0086"| "89"| "089"), "Yes"))
```

What I want:

| ID | DX1 | DX2 | DX3 | DX4 | DX5 | DX6 | DX7 | Diagnosis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05 | 87 | 04 | 05 | 67 | 75 | 86 | Yes |
| 2 | 89 | 05 | 99 | 26 | 86 | 06 | 87 | Yes |
| 3 | 99 | 21 | 23 | 21 | 44 | 24 | 66 |  |
| 4 | 87 | 26 | 05 | NA | 63 | 02 | 56 | Yes |
| 5 | 05 | 23 | 57 | NA | 18 | 86 | 65 |  |
| 6 | 67 | 44 | 46 | NA | 87 | 15 | 05 | Yes |
| 7 | NA | 89 | 90 | NA | 87 | 01 | 72 |  |
| 8 | NA | 13 | 89 | NA | 05 | 87 | NA | Yes |
| 9 | NA | 2 | 87 | NA | NA | NA | NA | Yes |

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Should `ID` 5 also be kept?

Comment: Yes, Sorry I was just making up the example

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` method without adding a Diagnosis variable:

```
rowAny <- function(x) rowSums(x) > 0

Patientdata %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(
    rowAny(
      across(
        starts_with("DX"), 
      ~ .x %in% c("05", "5", "02", "2", "36", "62","0062"), 
      .x %in% c("87", "087", "86", "0086", "89", "089"))))
```

You have ID in your example but not in your sample data, which is why it's added above.

This gives us:

```
   DX1 DX2 DX3  DX4  DX5  DX6  DX7 ID
1   05  87  04   05   67   75   86  1
2   89  05  99   26   86   06   87  2
3   87  26  05 <NA>   63   02   56  4
4   05  23  57 <NA>   18   86   65  5
5   67  44  16 <NA>   87   15   05  6
6 <NA>  13  89 <NA>   05   87 <NA>  8
7 <NA>   2  87 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>  9
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I actually didn't have a ID but do in my data set.
Instead of having a row summary is there a way to add a column even if it is binary Yes, No for the desired Diagnosis as above?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

With the help of akrun. Many thanks. Now I got the solution as desired by OP.

```
Patientdata %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  rowwise () %>% 
  mutate(Diagnosis = if(any(c_across(starts_with("DX")) %in% vector)) "Yes" else "No") %>% 
  ungroup ()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 8
  DX1   DX2   DX3   DX4   DX5   DX6   DX7   Diagnosis
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    
1 05    87    04    05    67    75    86    Yes      
2 89    05    99    26    86    06    87    Yes      
3 99    21    23    21    44    24    66    No       
4 87    26    05    NA    63    02    56    Yes      
5 05    23    57    NA    18    86    65    Yes      
6 67    44    16    NA    87    15    05    Yes      
7 NA    89    90    NA    87    01    72    Yes      
8 NA    13    89    NA    05    87    NA    Yes      
9 NA    2     87    NA    NA    NA    NA    Yes
```

**First solution**
I am not sure if you need this kind of solution.
Basically create a vector of your interested items
then use `across` with `ifelse`

```
library(tidyverse)

vector <- c("05", "5", "02", "2", "36", "62", "0062", "87", "087", "86", "0086", "89", "089")

Patientdata %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Diagnosis = across(starts_with("DX"),
                            ~ ifelse(. %in% vector, "Yes", "No")))
```

```
# A tibble: 9 x 8
  DX1   DX2   DX3   DX4   DX5   DX6   DX7   Diagnosis$DX1 $DX2  $DX3  $DX4  $DX5  $DX6  $DX7 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>         <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 05    87    04    05    67    75    86    Yes           Yes   No    Yes   No    No    Yes  
2 89    05    99    26    86    06    87    Yes           Yes   No    No    Yes   No    Yes  
3 99    21    23    21    44    24    66    No            No    No    No    No    No    No   
4 87    26    05    NA    63    02    56    Yes           No    Yes   No    No    Yes   No   
5 05    23    57    NA    18    86    65    Yes           No    No    No    No    Yes   No   
6 67    44    16    NA    87    15    05    No            No    No    No    Yes   No    Yes  
7 NA    89    90    NA    87    01    72    No            Yes   No    No    Yes   No    No   
8 NA    13    89    NA    05    87    NA    No            No    Yes   No    Yes   Yes   No   
9 NA    2     87    NA    NA    NA    NA    No            Yes   Yes   No    No    No    No
```

Comment: The reason is that you are specifying name while looping `across` resulting in a single `list` column.  Here, you could use `.names` to modify the name of the column/s  i..e `Patientdata %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("DX"),
                            ~ ifelse(. %in% vector, "Yes", "No"), .names = "Diagnosis_{.col}"))`

Comment: Thank you very much akrun. Is it possible to create only a Diagnosis column after DX7 without the $DX1...$D7. Like the desired output of the op!!! Many many thanks.

Comment: @TarJee Sorry, I didn't check the OP's post for expected output.  For that, you need `c_across` i.e. `Patientdata %>% as_tibble %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Diagnosis = if(any(c_across(starts_with("DX")) %in% vector)) "Yes" else "No") %>% ungroup`

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. Is there a way of only making one column?
Also as I mentioned about I am trying to select specific items as you mentioned. If patient have 1 of 5 diagnosis codes in one column but also have 1 or 5 of another diagnosis code in another. Thats why it has to search through the columns in various arrangements to see if the Diagnosis column would fit the inclusion criteria. It would be fine Yes, No

Comment: I added an answer but it is really a question for you guys below